# Javascript toggle without using class or id

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, semantics

i'm trying to show and hide a paragraph using javascript. But since this is a school project there are a few rules. I cannot use div class or id. This makes it hard for me to select the tags in Javascript. It has to be semantic, therefore the checkbox hack and the onclick attribute are not allowed.

here is the codepen https://codepen.io/SummerD/pen/pWXWdy

this is my html

```
<body>
<main>

  <section>

    <!-- Top part-->
    <span>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"/>
    </span>

    <!-- Bottom part-->
    <summary>
      <button>show paragraph</button>
      <h2>Moe</h2>
      <h3>leeg</h3>
      <p>blah blah blah, this is the paragraph  <a href="#">read more</a> </p>
      <footer>6 Minutes</footer>
    </summary>

  </section>

</main>
</body>
```

this is my css

```
section {
    width: 15em;
    margin: 2em;
    background-color: white;
    height: 23em;
}

  /*i'm trying to show/hide this p on click of the button*/

section summary p {
  display:none;
}
```

i've already tried this:

```
var section = document.querySelector('section > summary > p');
var button = document.querySelector('section > summary > button');

var show = function () {
    section.classList.toggle('show')
}

button.addEventListener('click', show);
```

with this css

```
section summary p {
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
  display:none;
}
section summary p.show {
  display:block;
}
```

but sadly this does not work. I don't know if it doesn't work because of a typo, because i honestly don't know what i'm doing, i'm really bad at javascript.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Are there any errors reported in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: The hole web is built around div, class and id's. Not using them would be just stupid... Anyhow, if you wanna try to hide/show a paragraf and have it more semantic without any use of javascript or checkbox hack, try using [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)

Comment: @endless according to my school div's are html4, and we have to use the html5 structural elements instead. We weren't allowed to use class or id in this particular project to practice with the css selectors.

Comment: "practice with the css selectors" Okey that's a good valid reason :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, the problem isn't with your button not being able to toggle (it actually does this just fine), but rather that you can't **click** on your button because `<section>` is being overlapped by `<main>`. This is because you have a **[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)** of `-1` on section (not shown in your code in the question), which means that it sits 'behind' `<main>`, which has the default `z-index` of `0` (technically `auto`, which inherits up to the default `0` for `<html>`).

Simply removing this will fix your problem:

```
section {
  /* z-index: 1 */
}
```

I've created a new pen showcasing this [**here**](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/JrQvRd), and added it to the following snippet:

```js
var section = document.querySelector('section > summary > p');
var button = document.querySelector('section > summary > button');

var show = function() {
  section.classList.toggle('show')
}

button.addEventListener('click', show);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Segoe UI, Myriad, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*=================
  =====the card====
  =================*/

section {
  width: 15em;
  margin: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2em 0.4em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 23em;
}

/*top part*/

span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

span img {
  width: 120%;
}

/*bottom part*/

section summary {
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}

section summary h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

section summary h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 1em;
  color: darkred;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

/*i'm trying to show/hide this p on click of the button*/

section summary p {
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  display: none;
}

section summary p.show {
  display: block;
}

section summary footer {
  margin: 2em 0 0;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <!-- Top part-->
      <span>
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"/> </span>
      <!-- Bottom part-->
      <summary>
        <button>show paragraph</button>
        <h2>Moe</h2>
        <h3>leeg</h3>
        <p>De buschauffeur port me wakker. We zijn bij de eindhalte, Centraal Station. Ik stap uit en duw de kinderwagen voort waarin mijn zoon ligt te slapen. Ik wou dat ik hem was. De mensen lopen in zichzelf gekeerd over het plein. De regen doet z’n best
          mij wakker te houden, maar mijn oogleden voelen zwaar, alsof er een stel verveelde kaboutertjes aan lopen te trekken. <a href="#">lees meer</a> </p>
        <footer>6 Minuten</footer>
      </summary>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Please consider bringing the code from the'Pen into the answer as a snippet to show the working code :)

Comment: The pen is fairly large; I'll include it and hide it by default :)